# how to access external mysql database in android?

Tags: android

I actually posted this question because **I found similar questions but not a perfect answer**. So coming to my question, I would like to **access a database from server**. As I'm new to android, I don't know what to do. Can anyone please help me **what should the steps to be taken**. I've already **gone through many sites** and found **some answers** like by using **soap or restful** services we can do this. But my actual problem is webservice. How to **create a webservice** or **what is the coding of webservice to handle requests from android** and also can someone post some sort of **sample code to access this external database(insert, update and delete).**

Please reply as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think webservices are too much complicated. You can write webserivces using any language. In my case we have developed a php script as webservie which reads data from mysql and sends as Json  object. Using HttpClient API we can invoke this php webservice and parse the Json object. Here is nice step by step tutorial on how to achieve this.

[access mysql data using php and httpclient](http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json/)
Update and inserts also follows sequence, but you will post data to php script which will update the mysql database.