# Android - guidelines - app with online database

Tags: android, database, remote-access

I want to create an app that is based on the data stored on remote database.

What i have in mind is to use a VPS i have to store the database. Then the app will, on demand, access (and update) the data on the database.

How should i set up my VPS in order to do that? Right now i just have a MYSQL server running.

---

**Edit**: I want to know what are the best practices i should follow in order to have an android app based on an online database.

- Can i access the db directly from the app?
- Do i need anything
  besides the database server to assist the communication of the db and
  the app?
- Should i use, for some reason, another db instead of mysql
  (faster,more secure, easier to connect)?

I am new to this and i would like some general guidelines.

Thanks.

Comment: While you are talking about creating an application, your specific question is "How should I setup up my VPS in order to do that?" which may be more geared for serverfault. Can you be more specific? Define "set up" (open firewall, install, design, access). I'm afraid your question may be closed because it is too general. Please read [ask].

Comment: Check my edit. I hope this is not too general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can i access the db directly from the app?**

As far as I know, no you still cannot access MySQL directly from Android. It has been a year since I did Android development, but you will most likely need something sitting in between (like a RESTful service, see http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/).

[How to access online mysql database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324939/how-to-access-online-mysql-database-in-android)

[how to access external mysql database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784122/how-to-access-external-mysql-database-in-android)

**Do i need anything besides the database server to assist the communication of the db and the app?**

Yes. See answer above.

**Should i use, for some reason, another db instead of mysql (faster,more secure, easier to connect)?**

That is up to you. There are some NoSQL solutions that offer a RESTful interface built in (I think CouchDB does this, MongoDB, etc...).